# I want to write a shell script to find the smallest filename(based on string length) in current directory

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script to find the smallest filename(based on string length) in current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(ls -trh *)
max=0;


for entry in ${data}
do
  echo ${entry}
len=${#entry}
echo ${len}
max1=${len}
echo ${max1}
echo ${max}
 if( $max1 -gt $max )
 then
 word=$entry
 max=$max1;
 fi;

done
```

Comment: Hi forte! Adding both your expected output and in what ways your script currently doesn't work will help us answer your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- you want:

   ```
   for entry in *
   ```
2. Quote `"$entry"` everywhere you use it: `echo "$entry"`
3. The syntax for your `if` condition is wrong:

   ```
   if [[ $max1 -gt $max ]]
   ```

Check your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

@forte: try:

```
ls | awk '{LEN=length($0);B[LEN]=B[LEN]?B[LEN] ORS $0:$0;;MIN=MIN<LEN?(MIN?MIN:LEN):LEN} END{print B[MIN]}'
```

Above should give you smallest name file(s), even if you have more than 1 file which are of same length and smallest it will give them all.

**EDIT1:** Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now successfully.

```
ls | awk '{
                LEN=length($0);
                B[LEN]=B[LEN]?B[LEN] ORS $0:$0;
                MIN=MIN<LEN?(MIN?MIN:LEN):LEN
          }
          END{
                print B[MIN]
             }
         '
```